# Access Controller Function defined in Anonymous Function into HTML5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have defined app.js to invoke Some-View.view.html and Some-View-controller.js. The Some-View.view.html has ng-click directive to call a function defined in Some-View-controller.js

Upon clicking the element with ng-click directive, function defined in Some-View-controller.js is not getting called.

Please let me know how to invoke function defined in Some-View-controller.js and also access variables linked to ng-model.

**app.js**

```
    .when('/Some-View', {
        controller: 'SomeViewController',
        templateUrl: 'Some-View/Some-View.view.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

**Some-View-controller.js**

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('SomeViewController', SomeViewController);

    SomeViewController.$inject = ['UserService', '$rootScope'];
    function SomeViewController(UserService, $rootScope) {
        /*Discussion Board related Functions*/ 
        var vm = this;

        /////
        vm.comments = [];
        vm.currCmtIndx=-1;
        vm.userReply="";


        function functionToBeCalledFrom_NG_CLICK() {            

        }   


        }
            /*End - Discussion Board related Functions*/    

        }   /*End - SomeViewController  */  

})();
```

**HTML Snippet**

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">                    
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle text-uppercase" type="button" id="submitComment" ng-click="vm.functionToBeCalledFrom_NG_CLICK()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" id="qazwsx"></span> Summit comment</button>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry for taking your attention for this pitty question. I had missed to assign the var into the controller to enable HTML to invoke it. I added vm.functionToBeCalledFrom_NG_CLICK=functionToBeCalledFrom_NG_CLICK; Able to invoke it now ! ! !

Comment: If you don't need help you can delete the question.

Comment: I guess, the question can be deleted by members with more than 10K reputation. Please let me know if I can delete it myself